# trapz intergation

Tags: matlab

I have an array of numbers and I want to integrate each column in the array seperatley, and in the end get back an array of numbers after the integration.

I tried "trapz" function but I get a single value, how can i do what I want above?

Here's my code:

```
t=-1:0.001:1;
x1=100*sinc(100*t);
x2= 100*(sinc(100*t)).^2;
W= -2000*pi:2*pi:2000*pi;
T=-1:0.001:1;
u=x1.*exp(-1i.*W.*t);
v=x2.*exp(-1i.*W.*t);
X11= trapz(t,u);
X22= trapz(t,v);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I mistaking or you are giving to trapz a 1D array, which are to be intended as values of a function on a grid. Therefore how can it return an array?

Comment: Currently, you're indeed passing a 1D array, so the output you see is indeed the integral along that column. What is the 2D array you wanted to construct?

Comment: Doesn't W contain several columns, I want to eventually plot the fourier transform of x1 and x2 by trapezoind integration.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why did you define both `T` and `t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following you correctly, you need `u` and `v` to be matrices. For that purpose, you have to resolve two issues in your code:

1. the `ω⋅t` product should be a matrix rather than a vector. For that purpose, you need to use matrix multiplication `W.' * t` (note the added transpose!) and not element-wise multiplication (`.*`). This produces all the necessary combinations of `ω⋅t` required for the transform.
2. In a similar fashion, you need to multiply `x` by `exp(-iωt)` column-wise. Use `bsxfun` instead of the element-wise multiplication, like so:

   ```
   u = bsxfun(@times, x1(:), exp(-i * W.' * t));
   ```

   The same applies for `v`.

Since you're using the same `exp(-i * W.' * t)` both for `u` and for `v`, I suggest computing it once and storing it in a variable:

```
E = exp(-i * W' * t);
u = bsxfun(@times, x1(:), E);
v = bsxfun(@times, x2(:), E);
```

Following this fix, `trapz` should produce the desired results now, *i.e.* `X11` and `X12` should really be the Fourier Transform applied on `x1` and `x2`, respectively.